# Test if socket is still open

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Following instruction from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255969/socket-io-client-to-client-messaging), I now have an array of connected users in socket.io. My problem (which I was warned of in the answer) is that sockets stay in this array even after the browser has disconnected.

I tried removing sockets from the array in a `socket.on('disconnect'`  function, but there is still a delay of ~1 minute between when the browser disconnects and socket.io triggers the disconnect.

What is the best way to "test" a socket to see if its actually alive? I am tempted to try to send a message and catch any errors, but I feel like there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: you could try reducing the `close timeout`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192747/socket-io-delay-in-firing-the-disconnect-event, default is 60s.

Answer (score 4):

Solution on how to test if "socket is still open"

```
if(socket.readyState === socket.OPEN)
{
}
```

Why it works:

> readyState = The current state of the connection; this is one of the Ready state
>   constants. Read only.
>
> "the Ready state constants" 
>   CONNECTING    0: The connection is not yet open. 
>   OPEN  1: The connection is open and ready to communicate. 
>   CLOSING   2: The connection is in theprocess of closing. 
>   CLOSED 3: The connection is closed or couldn't be opened.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in my disconnect handler. What I ended up using:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    users.splice(users.indexOf(socket), 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.on('end',function(){
//your code
})
```

or

```
socket.on('error',function(err){
//in case of any errors
})
```

The disconnect event wont fire until all the clients has been disconnected!